# JQuery hoverIntent / Drupal contrib hoverIntent module not working

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm trying to get the jquery plugin hoverIntent to work on my Drupal 7 installation. 
No luck.

1st, I tried the logical approach; simply the following to the theme .info file. 
scripts[] = js/jquery.hoverintent.js
Doesn't work, and causes other problems.

Then I tried the contrib hoverIntent module. I can see that the script is loaded on the page, but calling  .hoverIntent from within Drupal results in nothing happening.

```
$(function() {
  $(".views-field-field-profile-picture").hoverIntent(teamIn);
  $(".team-name-info").mouseleave(teamOut);   
});
```

Anyone with success in getting hoverIntent to work? Why is this so difficult?

Answer (score 0):

Found it. First, you will most likely see an error in the logs like this
 TypeError: cfg.out is undefined

The problem in my code is not that .hoverIntent wasn't loaded, it was that that method requires two parameters. (Obvious error)

Solution:

```
$(function() {
  $(".views-field-field-profile-picture").hoverIntent(teamIn, function(){});
  $(".team-name-info").mouseleave(teamOut);   
});
```